# Поставление placeholder в поля регистрации (Bitrix)?

Tags: битрикс, placeholder

Как поставить `placeholder` в поля регистрации. Прикрепил скрин регистрации. Там некоторые поля placeholder поставлены, а в некоторых не смог найти поля в коде. Не подскажите откуда найти эти поля поставить `placeholder`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а откуда форма? чем выводиться? где она в админке?

Comment: Форма сделано с компонентом "Настраиваемая регистрация". некоторое поля есть , некоторые.

Comment: Нужен код шаблона, а не скрин самой формы. Из настроек компонента плейсхолдеры не настроить. Нужно смотреть код шаблона компонента и разбираться где и куда дописывать.

Comment: как  вам показать весь код? здесь можно разместить?

Comment: здесь либо ссылкой на pastebin или аналог.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/akbarsulaymonov/9b2f6bc039a6a4047e999c37febf2206

Comment: вот я здесь просто добавил

Comment: можете посмотреть

Comment: в этом месте начинается подключение дополнительных полей `<?if($arResult["USER_PROPERTIES"]["SHOW"] == "Y"):?>` оно ограничено комментариями. там подключается дополнительный шаблон вам скорее всего туда. Поля логин и email вы добавляли в настройках компонента?

Comment: нет, они сами были... поля логин и email нужен их input

Comment: проверьте шаблон `bitrix:system.field.edit` он подключается в блоке `User properties` (выделен комментариями). В нем поидее либо должны быть эти поля и нужно просто прописать им placeholder либо добавить проверки на name поля input. Но гораздо лучше в шаблон добавить `placeholder = '$placeholder'`, а выше по необходимым условияем настроить заполнение переменной.